# Plotly: How to get the trace color attribute in order to plot selected marker with same color?

Tags: python, colors, plotly, plotly-python

I am trying to plot a selected marker for each of my traces in plotly. I would like to assign the same color to marker and line. Is there a way how to get the color attribute of my traces?

```
fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    name='trace01',
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(size=[0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0],
            color=[0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0])
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(size=[0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0],
            color=[0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0])
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Updated answer for newer versions of plotly:

For recent plotly versions, a larger number of the attributes of a plotly figure object are readable through `fig.data`. Now you can retrive the color for a line without defining it or following a color cycle through:

```
fig.data[0].line.color
```

To make things a bit more flexible compared to my original answer, I've put together an example where you can have multiple markers on the same line. Markers are organized in a dict like so:

```
markers = {'trace01':[[2,5], [4,9]],
           'trace02':[[3,9]]}
```

And the essence of my approach to getting the plot below is this snippet:

```
for d in fig.data:
    if d.name in markers.keys():
        for m in markers[d.name]:
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[m[0]], y = [m[1]],
                                      mode='markers',
                                      name=None,
                                      showlegend=False,
                                      marker=dict(color=d.line.color,size=15)
                                     )
                          )
```

Here you can see that I'm not actually using `fig.data[0].line.color`, but rather `color=d.line.color` since I've matched the markers with the traces by name through :

```
for d in fig.data:
    if d.name in markers.keys():
        for m in markers[d.name]:
```

#### Plot:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    name='trace01',
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    mode='lines',
   
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    line=dict(color='red'),
    mode='lines'
    
))

markers = {'trace01':[[2,5], [4,9]],
           'trace02':[[3,9]]}

for d in fig.data:
    if d.name in markers.keys():
        for m in markers[d.name]:
            fig.add_traces(go.Scatter(x=[m[0]], y = [m[1]],
                                      mode='markers',
                                      name=None,
                                      showlegend=False,
                                      marker=dict(color=d.line.color,size=15)
                                     )
                          )
            
fig.show()
```

---

#### Original answer for older versions

You can retrieve the color of a trace using:

```
fig['data'][0]['line']['color']
```

But you'll have to specify the color of the trace to be able to do so. Or you can make sure that the color of the markers follow the same sequence as the traces. But we can get to all the details if this is in fact what you're trying to accomplish:

[image]

If you study the code snippet below, you'll see that I, unlike you, havent defined the markers  in the same go as the lines. Rather, I've added the traces as pure lines with `mode='lines'` and then added separate traces for the markers with `mode='markers'`. When doing the latter, I've retrieved the colors of the corresponding lines using `color=data['line']['color']` in a loop:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    name='trace01',
    line=dict(color='blue'),
    mode='lines',
   
))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    line=dict(color='red'),
    mode='lines'
    
))

markers = [[2,5],
           [3,9]]

for i, data in enumerate(fig['data']):
    #print(data['line']['color'])
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[markers[i][0]], y=[markers[i][1]],
                   mode='markers',
                   name=None,
                   showlegend=False,
                   marker=dict(color=data['line']['color'],
                               size=15
                    )))
fig.show()
```

**Edit 1: How to do the same by referencing the default color sequence**

By default, plotly follows a color sequence that can be found using `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly`:

```
['#636EFA',
 '#EF553B',
 '#00CC96',
 '#AB63FA',
 '#FFA15A',
 '#19D3F3',
 '#FF6692',
 '#B6E880',
 '#FF97FF',
 '#FECB52']
```

The following snippet will produce the exact same figure as before, but without having to define the colors for the traces.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    name='trace01',
    mode='lines',

))
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    mode='lines'

))

colors = px.colors.qualitative.Plotly

markers = [[2,5],
           [3,9]]

for i, data in enumerate(fig['data']):
    #print(data['line']['color'])
    fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[markers[i][0]], y=[markers[i][1]],
                   mode='markers',
                   name=None,
                   showlegend=False,
                   marker=dict(color=colors[i],
                               size=15
                    )))
fig.show()
```

Comment: `fig['data'][0]['line']['color']` returns always `None` for me.

Comment: same issue - can not retrieve color if not explicitly defining it first `fig.data[0].line.color `. does not work as expected either in plotly version 5.3.1 which is fairly new at least ,but default colors for plotly graph objects  can be obtained (useful if not setting explicitly already and just need to copy default colors already used for other objects)  via `color=px.colors.qualitative.Plotly[trace_index]`

Comment: Did any of you find a resolution to where the data is hiding now? Or maybe it's been removed in a bug?

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the above answer, remember that `Plotly` in `px.colors.qualitative.Plotly` is the name of the color scheme used in the current template, which defaults to `Plotly`. You can use other color schemes, check their names and colors by doing this

```
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.colors.qualitative.swatches()
fig.show()
```

[Reference: https://plotly.com/python/discrete-color/]

Answer (score 1):

The best I have found is this:

```py
pio.templates[pio.templates.default].layout.colorway
```

Returns a list with the default colors of the current scheme. There are also colormaps for other cases in the current default layout in the same `.layout` object.

Answer (score 0):

Variation on @vestland answer using the same iterator but using `update_traces` and `selector`.
Works for this example but may not work for more complicated colour configurations?
In reality I think this just sets the marker colours to nothing and it then picks up the default colour sequence.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[0, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11],
    name='trace01',
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(size=[0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0],
            color=[0, 0, 10, 0, 0, 0])
))

fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(
    x=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    y=[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13],
    name='trace02',
    mode='lines+markers',
    marker=dict(size=[0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0],
            color=[0, 0, 0, 10, 0, 0])
))

# Set marker line color to same color as marker for each trace
for i, data in enumerate(fig['data']):
    fig.update_traces(marker_color=data['line']['color'],
                      selector=dict(name=data['name']))

fig.show()
```

[image: example of output figure from above code sample]